Color del fondo de mi NavBar y Footer no se muestran hasta el final de la pantalla
Mi problema es que cada vez que creo una web y le coloco un color al fondo se muestra perfectamente en mi pantalla. Pero cuando voy a probar en F12 (responsive), sucede esto que nunca pude solucionar:

Como se puede observar, los elementos se achican dejando ver el fondo del body siempre del lado derecho. He probado la web en varios dispositivos con una pantalla de ese estilo, y efectivamente si se ven así. ¿Qué podría cambiar? ¿Es una opción de CSS que no conozca? Aclaro que soy principiante en esto, y esta web es un pequeño proyecto de mi instituto. A continuación, colocaré los estilos que tengo puestos en mi navbar y footer:
.navbar{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

footer{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 75px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #000080;
    width: 100%;
}


Por que no intentas utilizar boostrap :  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/ es probable que te ayude a resolver el tema de los espacios, tamaños y mas que otra cosa el responsive.  Saludos

Como tu código es HTML + CSS, procura mostrar un [repro] ejecutable (a través de un snippet, con el botón que indica <>). ¿Están bien cerradas todas las etiquetas HTML de tu código?

Tienes que agregar el HTML junto con el CSS para poder comprobar nosotros acá. De todos modos, veo que usas width 100%, el cual tomará el tamaño del contenedor en el que esté, asi que al cambiar a responsive, ese contenedor cambia.

@ssjuan23ss ¿Tienes esta línea en tu HTML: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />? (Si no está, ponla dentro del <head>)

Puedes cambiar el tamaño de tu navbar usando @media de css, qui te dejo un ejemplo.
Para que veas el resultado as chica y grande tu pantalla.


body {
  background-color: yellow;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
  
    #contenedor {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 1em;
        border: #000 solid 1px;
    }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

<div id="contenedor">
  <h1>The @media Rule</h1>

  <p>Resize the browser window. When the width of this document is 600 pixels or less, the background-color is "lightblue", otherwise it is "yellow".</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>




No respondas preguntas de este estilo en donde el html + css hacen toda la diferencia, si el OP tiene un problema verificable en código, debe mostrarlo.
